# Enable/disable AVRCP per device? (BlueZ + PulseAudio, Arch)

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Arch Linux with linux kernel 5.15.12-arch1-1, bluez 5.62-1, pulseaudio 15.0.

I have a speaker and headphones. When using the speaker, I want a single volume scale that can be controlled both from my laptop and with the volume keys on the speaker - and this is the default behavior. However, when using the headphones I want separate volume scales for my system and the headphones (so that change of volume with the headphones' keys is not seen by the system), and the only way I found to achieve this is to disable AVRCP by running `/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` with the `--noplugin=avrcp` argument. The obvious problem with this solution is that the option applies to all the bluetooth devices in the system.

Is it possible to disable AVRCP per device? Or is there a better solution I could use to separate volume scale for my headphones?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that solves your problem separate volume scales, but at least under the X window environment my bluetooth headset shows up as an X input device (as listed by `xinput`).
This means by disabling the corresponding device (`xinput --disable <id>`) I can deactivate the effect of the AVRCP commands of a specific device.

Comment: Good point! Worth noting headphones will work fine afterwards, except e.g. in my case they stop sending annoying sporadic "PAUSE" events *(which come from their light detector noticing a luminosity change or whatever)*.